# Where is the Class Library for .Net Core template in Visual Studio Community 2022 or Visual Studio Community 2022 Preview?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core-3.1

As the title asks, I can't seem to find this template.

Help please.

TIA

Comment: i think hier "...isual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows\1033\ClassLibrary"

Comment: @MihalBy  As far as I can tell, that is only for .NET Framework and not .NET Core :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found exactly which template it is, there is a proyect templated called simply "Class library", with the description "A project for creating a class library that targets .NET or .NET Standard" then the next step it asks the target framework and here you can choose .NET Core 3.1 or any version you have enabled in the individual components of Visual Studio Installer.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have added Console App and then converted it's Output type to Class Library.